# Java advert library for desktop applications

Tags: java, desktop-application, ads

I'm looking to add a few adverts(like AdSense) into my free application and tried to search around for some advert libraries for Java but was unable to find any. I found a few for Android but none just for plain Java. Is there any? Any suggestions on adding adverts would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Google offer their own APIs for Java, including [code for management of AdSense](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#AdSense_Management_API) but it does not seem to offer the ability to fetch adverts. And if Google don't offer a way to do something it often means they don't want you to do it.

Reading the [Google AdSense Standard Terms & Conditions](https://www.google.com/adsense/terms) it is very specific about where adverts can be used, and software applications are not named, so I suspect you would need to get written permission from Google before you attempted to include AdSense ads in an application. If you violate the terms and Google catch you then they will simply close your AdSense account, and from what I hear they are pretty unforgiving.